# Plain Javascript event lister on file picked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to attach an event lister to a file input.
I was thinking it would work like this. But i have read online and cant seem to get it to work.

```
    <input type="file" id=image1 >

    var image1 = document.getElementsByID("image1");

    image1.addEventListener('change', alert(1));
```

Comment: because you are assigning what alert returns to the change event....

Comment: `image1.addEventListener('change', function() { alert(1) });`

Comment: Here let me apply event to it i still get the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var image1 = document.getElementsByID("image1");
image1.addEventListener('change', alert(1));
```

to this:

```
var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
image1.addEventListener('change', function(){ alert(image1); });
```

Because `getElementsByID()` is not a valid method call, but `getElementById()` is.

Also, so that you will be executing a function that invokes the `alert()`, rather than invoking the `alert` immediately and assigning the result of the `alert` as the `click` event handler, we need to wrap the `alert()` in a function.

Lastly, `alert(1)` doesn't show anything because `1` isn't a variable, nor is it a string. You should be writing `alert(image1.someProperty)`. Since `image1` is a `file` type, you could access the files associated with the element and then a specific file and then an aspect of that file.

Here's the whole thing:

```js
var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");

image1.addEventListener('change', function(){ 
  var files = image1.files;
  alert(files[0].name); 
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id=image1 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

input.onclick = function () {
    this.value = null;
};

input.onchange = function () {
    alert(this.value);
};
```

```html
<input type='file' value='C:\fakepath' />
```

Comment: It's better to use `.addEventListener()` than `onXyz` event properties as `addEventListener()` follows modern W3C DOM Event standards and is more robust than `onXyz`.

Comment: Oh, ok. Will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="file" id="image1" onchange="alert(1);" />`

Comment: Inline HTML event attributes should not be used.

Comment: Why not? Is it not standard ES/HTML?

Comment: It is part of the HTML5 standard, but not part of the DOM Event Standard. Here's a link to a previous answer of mine that explains the many reasons not to ever use them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991

Comment: And, here's a link to the DOM Event Standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events

Comment: Ha! I rarely write such low-level code these days, so I'm obviously not up-to-snuff on those specific best practices. I can't think of a single web app I've written in the past 3 years where it would have been appropriate for me to use an inline handler.

I guess this question seemed to me to be pitched from an academic point of view, so I provided a strictly academic answer.

Thanks for the great info!

Comment: Frankly, inline HTML event handlers haven't been appropriate since about 2001.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.